# How to export PDFs files with subfolders from Mendeley?

Tags: mendeley

When I export PDFs from Mendeley I get all pdfs in the same folder. How to keep them organized and also export annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mendeley app doesn't have this capability, but there is a python tool to do so.

1. Install Anaconda for python 2 https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Don't forget to add `export PATH="/home/vitor/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"` to your `.bashrc` or terminal.

2. Install PyPDF2 https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyPDF2/1.26.0

   `python setup.py install`
3. Download Menotexport https://github.com/Xunius/Menotexport
4. Install Menotexport

   `conda create -n menotexport python=2.7
   source activate menotexport
   conda install -c guangzhi menotexport`
5. `python menotexport-gui.py`
6. Choose `~/.local/share/data/Mendeley\ Ltd./Mendeley\ Desktop/your_email@www.mendeley.com.sqlite` as Mendeley Data file

More information at https://github.com/Xunius/Menotexport